# Программирование, одновременное выполнение кода

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, у меня немного странный вопрос, который похож на паранойю, но так и есть.

Допустим в php коде есть элементарная проверка:

```
if(!$db->get(SELECT выбираем запись из таблицы)) {
//и если записи нет то делаем внос
$db->query(INSERT);
}
```

То есть при таких условиях, невозможно иметь две записи одновременно.

Не обессудьте, но что если произойдет *редчайшее явление когда две звезды  окажутся на параллельном уровне относительно друг друга*, и два пользователя **одновременно** отправят запрос, и  у первого произойдет проверка отсутствия записи которая вернет true, после чего произойдет внесение данных. Но так как два пользователя отправили запрос в одно и тоже время, у второго проверка записи будет выполнена в то же время, и не успеет вернуть `false`, так как внесение данных от первого пользователя ещё не произошло.

Получается поимеем две записи?

Такое вообще возможно? Не только в php, а и в программировании в целом.

Comment: Возможно и весьма распространено. В разных СУБД задача решается по разному. Но везде в основе решения лежат транзакции и блокировки

Comment: По моему тут есть такие варианты. 1 вариант. В базе данных можно прописать уникальность для сочетания полей.
2 вариант. Выполнять через механизм транзакции. Делаете проверку. Начинаете транзакцию. Делаете запись. Делаете вторую проверку И если есть дубликаты, то отменяете транзакцию. Если нет завершаете транзакцию.

Comment: Или, включаете проверку в саму операцию вставки, в большинтсве СУБД есть что то впроде `insert ... on conflict ...` которая не будет вставлять запись, если она уже есть. Так же можно делать `insert ... select ... from ... where not exists(select ... проверяем что записи еще нет)`

Answer (score 1):

> Получается поимеем две записи? Такое вообще возможно?

Да и да. Если не предприняты **меры предосторожности**.

Стандартная мера в этом случае, если у вас [ACID-гарантии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) от СУБД: воспользоваться C, consistency, согласованностью. Вам нужно объяснить СУБД, что для ваших данных означает *быть согласованными*, и СУБД вам это обеспечит.

Стандартная ситуация, при которой это возникает: когда некое поле должно быть **уникальным** во всех записях таблицы. Скажем, может прийти одновременно две просьбы добавить в БД число 42, а на тот момент его там ещё нет. Да, они оба проверят, что этого числа ещё в базе нет, и оба выпишут команду "вставляй 42". Но...

Можно заранее объявить, что поле в таблице должно в каждой записи быть уникальным. Называется это объявление **"ограничение уникальности"** (uniqueness constraint). Когда оно существует, добавление одинаковых значений в разных записях приводит к нарушению согласованности, что для ACID-совместимых баз обычно *гарантированно невозможно*.

...и в итоге один из `INSERT`'ов завершится ошибкой.

---

Если у вас в СУБД нет гарантии согласованности, то придётся заниматься местечковым велосипедостровением, чтобы обеспечить такую согласованность самостоятельно с помощью разнообразных средств обеспечения thread safety: блокировками, [CAS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC)'ом или ещё чем.